# Unable to receive email to my own email server from outside

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, mx-record

I am creating a mail server for my domain. I bought a domain from GoDaddy.com. Domain is crazywako.info.

I have webserver on that machine too. It is running Ubuntu 12.04 with postfix, courier-imap, and roundcube  +  squirrelmail.

I can receive email if I sent it with Roundcube sender as: user@crazywako.info.

But when I try to send email from my gmail account I cant receive it on Ubuntu's end.

I have MX set to crazywako.info in my dns-provider settings http://dy.fi. MXTOOLBOX also says that my MX is set to crazywako.info: http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3acrazywako.info#

My ISP is blocking SMTP port 25 and I use my ISP's smtp to send emails: smtp.dnainternet.net. I have 193 IMAP and 25 SMTP ports open on my router.

Any ideas why I can't receive any emails?

EDIT:::

```
This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification

THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.

YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.

Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:
joni@crazywako.info

Message will be retried for 2 more day(s)

Technical details of temporary failure:
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=7720
[crazywako.info. (10): Connection timed out]

----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
       d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
       h=mime-version:in-reply-to:references:date:message-id:subject:from:to
        :content-type;
       bh=mmGE32TDWbOiSxQr9BTe9YCQ3uFTF2+ttNYpRsm31PU=;
       b=HQ0eEnMGDq/UyHbW7IY252CNcqYPXZpZg971SuQkK9A0LOifl7CZBqt38afzVYexwM
        OfrW+pUEbY+HaICT9CIxcAozexfIaiPyzscHMIO9zoeP0YA85eygz1+EVlWjLzS5FAYw
        vEN15LkCzNeCWFbb1aSHmsixILmmXdXBDVuWRcXZoGXITmzhDggrxZ3rQDocjZcfr3ti
        tTIE1o2L0nIZyCZGOZq58Bv+0heFGtu/4QoLuOrgDeOQRQFl3qTQxgh6e9j3eUBK5fMk
        vv03SXz5SrkBSVbc3ce1A43Ns0Cd0/2yep6oQjHUGUiZ9izVMzNmGD/fSum/FdUGLpJ4
        qdbQ==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.236.195.34 with SMTP id o22mr4433268yhn.75.1334894281860; Thu,
 19 Apr 2012 20:58:01 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.147.111.15 with HTTP; Thu, 19 Apr 2012 20:58:01 -0700 (PDT)
In-Reply-To: <cb2cfc632a314a682c795c2676515d3e@crazywako.info>
References: <cb2cfc632a314a682c795c2676515d3e@crazywako.info>
Date: Fri, 20 Apr 2012 06:58:01 +0300
Message-ID: <CACLZ8tNJvgAaPysaQ3-jP4wiVd2rZD7gejp1TOkcyQtP5UTcQA@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Re: moi z<3
From: Joni Rautiainen <jonirautiainen@gmail.com>
To: joni <joni@crazywako.info>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=20cf3056389f7ba84b04be144b38
```

Comment: Are you sure your ISP is not blocking port 25 inbound as well? Can you telnet from outside your network to port 25 on your mail server?

Comment: Thanks for the tip... It seems I can't "telnet crazywako.info 25" from outside. Hmm... Can I somehow change the port for SMTP

Comment: Did you check your IPTables rules on Ubuntu as well? I'd start by disabling the firewall on Ubuntu momentarily while you troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Webmin tells that Linux Firewalls doenst have any rules so there is nothing its blocking. I am running ftp, ssh, apache servers on it and those are working as normal

Comment: **My ISP is blocking SMTP port 25 and I use my ISP's smtp to send emails: smtp.dnainternet.net. I have 193 IMAP and 25 SMTP ports open on my router.** - If you know this and appreciate what it means then your question makes no sense. If you know your ISP is blocking port 25 then this is clearly why you can't receive anything. There's not really anything you can do about this if they won't unblock it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Because you said so yourself.

Your ISP does not allow you to run a mail server on this Internet connection.